# Redirect to a page when it's ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The main page, say http://mysite/main, of a site is slow sometimes, I want to create an index.html HTML page which does the following

1. It shows some splash image. And at the same time it try to get http://mysite/main
2. Wait for 5 seconds
3. If http://mysite/main is ready, redirect to it
4. Otherwise wait till http://mysite/main is ready.

How to implement the function? Should it use jQuery or simple iframe/js?

Comment: Do you try to use loading page, example : http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/ instead ?

Comment: Tried utilizing `$(window).on("load", function() {/*loading icon*/}); $(document).ready(function() {/* remove loading icon, do stuff */})` ?

Comment: @kwan245 The link sounds good. However, the user want to display the splash page for a few seconds no matter what. Also the http://mysite/main page will redirect to login page if it's not login. (I may be able to use the method on login page if the slowness is caused by it only but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: The loading icon will able to do the same as what you want. I am also not sure why the user want splash page if the page already ready.

Comment: @kwan245 I don't get it too and tried to change their mind. They want to see a splash page for a while before enter the page.

Comment: I modified my answer by adding timeout component so you will have at least 5 mins of splash time. Same can be applied to loading icon approach too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery :

What you can do is for index.html to have 2 panel / div :

1) for loading page

2) for actual content http://mysite/main

And in jquery you will show the 1st panel only .show() until .ready() executed which then you hide 1st panel and show 2nd panel.

```
$("#first").show();
$("#second").load("http://mysite/main", function(){

setTimeout(
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#first").hide();
    $("#second").show();
   }),300000);
});
```

It is better to use loading icon as per http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Comment: The  http://mysite/main will return full html doc, which include `<html>`. Is it OK to load it to a panel/div?

Comment: This will go when mysite/main is loaded immediately without the minimum 5 second wait